# How do I get back onto my servers after changing my name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While playing Minecraft, I changed my name and now I can't access any servers. I've tried logging out and back on, but it still won't work. I'm afraid that I may not be able to play Minecraft anymore...

Comment: Did you *actually* log out? As in, did you open the launcher and click "log out"?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Are these servers whitelisted? That would be a simple exclamation!

Comment: What was the error message you got?

Comment: what version of minecraft are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely just need to go in to the console and type `/whitelist add {new name}`

Answer (score 0):

1. The Session ID that your client is using, might be out of date.

Try logging out & in in the Minecraft Launcher.

If that does not work, you might want to go to your .minecraft folder (located at %appdata% on Windows, and in your /home/ directory on Linux) and delete the file called 'launcher_profiles.json'. After this, go to your launcher and log in.

2. You are playing in an old version (specifically in a lower one than 1.7.6, not including 1.7.6) or with mods.
3. You have been banned from the servers, or if they are whitelisted, you are not whitelisted anymore.